# update most recent rows only?

Tags: postgresql, update

I have a database of a garage of rented cars with a table called Cars with the following columns :

*Type,First_seen_in_garage,Last_seen_in_garage*

The table initially have the following rows :

```
Ferrari,2002-10-13 07:12:58,2002-10-13 10:12:58
Lambo,2002-10-13 08:12:58,2002-10-13 11:12:58
Renault,2002-10-13 09:12:58,2002-10-13 12:12:58
Ferrari,2002-10-13 10:12:58,2002-10-13 15:12:58
```

Now I have the following row from which I have to update the initial table :

```
*Ferrari,2002-10-14 08:12:58,2002-10-14 10:12:58*
*Renault,2002-10-13 23:12:58,2002-10-14 23:12:58*
*Lambo,2002-10-13 23:12:58,2002-10-14 23:12:58*
```

in order to become :

```
Ferrari,2002-10-13 07:12:58,2002-10-13 10:12:58
Lambo,2002-10-13 08:12:58,2002-10-14 23:12:58
Renault,2002-10-13 09:12:58,2002-10-14 23:12:58
Ferrari,2002-10-13 10:12:58,2002-10-14 10:12:58
```

Note that for the Ferrari rows I want to keep the first instance as it is and update only the second one

I could do it with an UPDATE .. SET .. WHERE if there was only one Ferrari instance however the previous query updates the two rows which is not what I want ..

Help Please.

Comment: update with what? and what if then where a 5 Ferraris and 8 Renaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't tell us ´,w hat for an Update you will have,

I selected one . where the lst of a type get 5 Minutes more on his End time, this is of corse only an example for an   update, to show how it works.

The latest seen time we get from the WINDOW Function  `MAX OVER PArtition`
And the update only update the types with the latest time (i choose Last_seen_in_garage) because the update only updates the rows , that are joined together

In the new query i also check out the same data from the temptaböe(see that Ferrair has now 2020 date as Last_seen_in_garage and use those data to update the CARS table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Cars  (
>   "Type" VARCHAR(7),
>   "First_seen_in_garage" timestamp ,
>   "Last_seen_in_garage" timestamp 
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Cars 
>   ("Type", "First_seen_in_garage", "Last_seen_in_garage")
> VALUES
>   ('Ferrari', '2002-10-13 07:12:58', '2002-10-13 10:12:58'),
>   ('Lambo', '2002-10-13 08:12:58', '2002-10-13 11:12:58'),
>   ('Renault', '2002-10-13 09:12:58', '2002-10-13 12:12:58'),
>   ('Ferrari', '2002-10-13 10:12:58', '2002-10-13 15:12:58');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
>   CREATE TABLE Tmp_table  (
>   "Type" VARCHAR(7),
>   "First_seen_in_garage" timestamp ,
>   "Last_seen_in_garage" timestamp 
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Tmp_table 
>   ("Type", "First_seen_in_garage", "Last_seen_in_garage")
> VALUES
>   ('Ferrari', '2002-10-13 07:12:58', '2002-10-13 10:12:58'),
>   ('Lambo', '2002-10-13 08:12:58', '2002-10-13 11:12:58'),
>   ('Renault', '2002-10-13 09:12:58', '2002-10-13 12:12:58'),
>   ('Ferrari', '2020-10-13 10:12:58', '2020-10-13 15:12:58');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
>  UPDATE Cars
> SET "Last_seen_in_garage" = maxtempcar."maxdateime"
> FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Cars."Type",
>        MAX("Last_seen_in_garage") OVER (PARTITION BY Cars."Type") "maxdateime"
>        FROM Cars) maxcar 
> INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Tmp_table."Type",
> MAX("Last_seen_in_garage") OVER (PARTITION BY Tmp_table."Type") "maxdateime"
> FROM Tmp_table) maxtempcar ON maxtempcar."Type" = maxcar."Type" 
> WHERE Cars."Type" = maxcar."Type" AND Cars."Last_seen_in_garage" = maxcar."maxdateime";
> ```

> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM Cars
> ;
> ```

> ```
> Type    | First_seen_in_garage | Last_seen_in_garage
> :------ | :------------------- | :------------------
> Ferrari | 2002-10-13 07:12:58  | 2002-10-13 10:12:58
> Lambo   | 2002-10-13 08:12:58  | 2002-10-13 11:12:58
> Renault | 2002-10-13 09:12:58  | 2002-10-13 12:12:58
> Ferrari | 2002-10-13 10:12:58  | 2020-10-13 15:12:58
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fc636c7f7ae0650e28095411635dc1f2)*

Comment: The update will occur from the data of the next day so in this case the interval trick will not work for me because I have to get the data from the temporary table in which I have stored the new Last_seen_in_garage values

Comment: as i commented and wrote also here, the query is sound,and takes the little information ´, that you gave. I think you can go from there and see if it works, else post the query, for clarification

Comment: instead of update Cars   you take any table you want, what th eupdatein table needs is Type and the connectiomng date to identofy the row that must be updated.

Comment: The table Cars allows me to have duplicates in the column type but whenever I get the new data I have to update only the last seen value of the last occurrence of each distinct type

Comment: that ios what the updates makes, as you see with the Ferrari, only the row with '2002-10-13 15:12:58 as Last_seen_in_garage       gets update to 2002-10-13T15:17:58.000Z, so it does what you wanted.the subselct gets the last of each type and uses that to update the correct row

Comment: I know but the problem here is that the table from which I want to do the update is another table so the SET Part would be something like this "Last_seen_in_garage" = Tmp_table."Last_seen_in_garage"  will this work too ?

Comment: no, because the database doesn't know which value you mean. so what is temptable how relates it to cars and it rows.?

Comment: temptable is a temporary table that contains the new data(Type, FS,LS) that changes everyday I have a script that creates this temporary table from which I need to update my Data

Comment: so  basically you beed the Last_seen_in_garage       of the temporarytable and wnaty that to inout into the Last_seen_in_garage       of the cars table?

Comment: yes without changing the other Ferrari rows just the most recent one

Comment: it is qutie simple you need only the same data from the temo_table. see please the updated answer